# How can I boot my usb from grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb-drive

I am dual booting ubuntu 11.04 and windows 7 and I have a bootable usb flash drive.
How can I configure grub so it will boot my flash drive?

Comment: FYI, many computers these days have a boot menu where you can choose the drive you boot to. Perhaps you have your reasons for wanting to do this in grub, but I find this method easier.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways. There is an application in Ubuntu Software Center called Startup-Manager, which can be used to edit grubs menu. It's not actively supported or developed since a couple of months ago though. The developer of Startup-manager recommends a software called Grub-customizer, which you can find here: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer. Both of those applications are GUI apps.

You can edit the boot menu yourself.

But most BIOSes have a keyboard shortcut to display a boot menu from which you choose which device you want to boot from. That is a better solution, because then you don't have to do anything special to either device. You'll just install grub on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out correctly by Jo Erland: the  method below refers to the old grub.
I should check how it works with the new grub2.
However, I still think that it is better to start the grub command line and to try booting using that command line than to edit the grub configuration directly. I will have a look tonight. In the meantime I still leave my old post here for reference.

> You have to make sure that your bios supports booting from usb, and
>   the usb drive should be enabled as a bootable device. If this is the
>   case, you can follow the procedure outlined here to boot once from
>   usb: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB You usb drive will
>   most likely be hd(1,0) if it is the second device from which the bios
>   can boot.
>
> It is best to test this first, and once you find a combination that
>   works, you can edit your menu.lst to add a permanent entry (also
>   outlined in the above page).
>
> Apart from that: most bioses support a hotkey to choose the boot
>   device (often F12). In that case you can boot from usb without having
>   to edit the grub configuration.

Comment: Doesn't that page refer to Grub Legacy?

Answer (score 0):

What device it appears as in hardware listing is dependent on BIOS and hardware boot options.  If it already has an OS on it just connect it and run update-grub.  It should find it that way.  It's my understanding that grub2 uses UUIDs instead of hd(x,y) except for where it stores /boot.  Just a couple thoughts.  It should just work.